# Error computing KL divergence in Scipy

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning, scipy, signal-processing

I am trying to calculate KL divergence using the [entropy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html) function of scipy.

My `p` is:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

and `q` is:

```
array([[ 0.05242718,  0.04436347,  0.04130855,  0.04878344,  0.04310538,
         0.02856853,  0.03303122,  0.02517992,  0.08525434,  0.03450324,
         0.14580068,  0.1286993 ,  0.28897473],
       [ 0.65421444,  0.11592199,  0.0642645 ,  0.02989768,  0.01385762,
         0.01756484,  0.01024294,  0.00891479,  0.01140301,  0.00718939,
         0.00938009,  0.01070139,  0.04644726],
       [ 0.65984136,  0.13251236,  0.06345234,  0.02891162,  0.02429709,
         0.02025307,  0.01073064,  0.01170066,  0.00678652,  0.00703361,
         0.00560414,  0.00651137,  0.02236522],
       [ 0.32315928,  0.23900077,  0.05460232,  0.03953635,  0.02901102,
         0.01294443,  0.02372061,  0.02092882,  0.01188251,  0.01377188,
         0.02976672,  0.05854314,  0.14313218],
       [ 0.7717858 ,  0.09692616,  0.03415596,  0.01713088,  0.01108141,
         0.0128005 ,  0.00847301,  0.01049734,  0.0052889 ,  0.00514799,
         0.00442508,  0.00485477,  0.01743218]], dtype=float32)
```

When I do:

```
entropy(p[0],q[0])
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-201-563ea7d4decf> in <module>()
      4 print('p0:',p[0])
      5 print('q0:',q[0])
----> 6 entropy(p[0],q[0])

/Users/freelancer/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/mlab.py in entropy(y, bins)
   1570     y = np.zeros((len(x)+2,), x.dtype)
   1571     y[1:-1] = x
-> 1572     dif = np.diff(y)
   1573     up = (dif == 1).nonzero()[0]
   1574     dn = (dif == -1).nonzero()[0]

/Users/freelancer/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in histogram(a, bins, range, normed, weights, density)
    781         if (np.diff(bins) < 0).any():
    782             raise ValueError(
--> 783                 'bins must increase monotonically.')
    784 
    785         # Initialize empty histogram

ValueError: bins must increase monotonically.
```

Why is it?

Comment: Please do not post errors/code as screen shot but copy in the text.

Comment: @kazemakase done

Comment: @ VeilEclipse [thank you](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3005167) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works with the example arrays:

```
import scipy as sp
sp.stats.entropy(p[0], q[0])
```

Looking at the stack trace in the error massage, it becomes apparent that you did not call [scipy's `entropy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html) function but [matplotlib's `entropy`](https://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.entropy), which works differently.
Here is the relevant part:

> `/Users/freelancer/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/`**`matplotlib/mlab.py`**`in entropy(y, bins)`

Comment: Thanks for that.
I imported both matplotlib and explicitly scipy's entropy. Maybe it got conflicted

Comment: @VeilEclipse Yes, that can happen. Results may depend on the order of imports and things like that. For this reason it's usually a [bad idea to `import *`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/3005167) into the global namespace - even if it seems convenient at first.